# When I try to select text, I often paste when I don't want to

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad P16 Gen 1.

When I want to select text, I click the touchpad with one finger and then with another finger, I drag the cursor over the text I want to select. I can't reliably reproduce it, but I have noticed that if I do this on the right hand side of the pad, usually it just pastes whatever I had saved in my clipboard. So somehow, it is treating this gesture as a middle click somehow?

I have looked in my settings but I don't see any obvious way to turn it off.

Any ideas about how to stop this?

Comment: Use a USB mouse, and stay away from the touchpad.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue - it is very much dependent on the touchpad brand likely. Also, do you use Xorg or Wayland? I cannot even reproduce a middle click, so cannot use the primary keyboard to start with - I actually notice right now that I can by tapping with three fingers. I never used the primary clipboard. For me, hitting Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V to paste is much more reliable.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. I wasn't sure if using Xorg or Wayland, but when I do `env` I see that `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11`. And yes I agree, I also used Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V; the issue is that when I use the trackpad to select text, it sometimes paste.

And further investigation has led me to realise that the middle bottom of the trackpad is  assigned as a middle click which is why it is pasting sometimes:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438725/disabling-middle-click-on-bottom-of-a-clickpad-touchpad
So I need to figure out how to switch that off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, at the bottom of my trackpad are pressable left, middle and right click buttons.

[This link](https://linuxhint.com/map-a-mouse-button-in-linux/) shows how to reassign them so that I could fix the accidental paste problem.